# how to get all the controllers that get hits using debug eclipse mars cakephp

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, cakephp

i want to get all the controllers that gets hits during debug process.i have tried to debug with putting a debug point at index function though it does not get hit at there.Then afterwards i put a debug point at dispatcher controller and it did not work either.i want to get list of controllers that connected each other.

Comment: If your app uses more than one controller at the same time you do something **fundamentally** wrong...

Answer (score 0):

just put this code your in your app_controller you will see the magic

```
function beforeFilter() {    
        $siteConfig = array();
        //put this code 
        $this->log("ACL : Controller - ".$this->params['controller']. " Action - ".$this->params['action'], 'debug');
        }
```